# Two database configurations

Tags: hibernate, orm, playframework, playframework-2.0

I using hibernate with play 2.4.
Why do i need to add configurations for db in both application.conf and hibernate.cfg.xml.
i need to make the configuration in one place only for consistency.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could follow [Play's JPA tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaJPA) and use Hibernate as a JPA implementation. This way the configuration is done in the `persistance.xml` instead of `hibernate.cfg.xml` and Play's own `conf/application.conf`.

Most your Hibernate/JPA configurations go into `conf/META-INF/persistence.xml` but you also have define something like driver, url and name in the `conf/application.conf`:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
```

Comment: so anyway we will define db url in two places?

Comment: Yes. Although I've never tried to do it all in the persistence.xml. Maybe it's enough.